# Inserting series data in highcharts dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to highcharts and I am trying to create a highchart by passing the data from my controller file to my view file.Unfortunetely, I am not able to put data in my series dynamically. Given below are my controller and view files:

#### Controller:graph.php

```
<?php
class Graph extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function index() {

            $data['title']='Graph for hourly distribution of results based on Location';
            $xaxis=array('2','4','6','8','10');
            $y1axis=array(5,8,4,6,4);
            $y2axis=array(4,6,8,4,5);
            $yaxis=array($y1axis,$y2axis);
            $data['xlabel']='X-Axis Name';
            $data['ylabel']='Y-Axis Name';
            $data['type']='line';
            $arry = array('xdata' => $xaxis,'ydata' => $yaxis,'title' => $data['title'],'type' => $data['type'],'xlabel' => $data['xlabel'],'ylabel' => $data['ylabel']);
            $this -> load -> view('graph_js', $arry);
        } 

    }

?>
```

#### Viewfile:graph_js.php

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Highcharts-2.2.5/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Highcharts-2.2.5/js/modules/exporting.js">    </script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },

        title: {
            text: '<?php echo $title ?>',
            x: -20 //center
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: '<?php echo $xlabel ?>',
            x: -20
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '<?php echo $ylabel ?>'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        series: []

    }
            options.xAxis=new Array();
            options.xAxis[0] = new Object();
            options.xAxis[0].categories = new Array(<?php echo join(", ", $xdata) ?>);

            options.series = new Array();

            var i;
            var j=<?php echo count($ydata) ?>;
            <?php echo $k=0; ?>;
            for(i=0;i<j;i++)
            {
                options.series[i] = new Object();
                options.series[i].name = 'Sample'+i;
                options.series[i].data = new Array(<?php echo join(", ", $ydata[$k++]) ?>);

            }

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);         

});

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The code above draws the 1st series of the graph and overlaps the 2nd series on the 1st series itself, but if I try to do it manually by putting the following code instead of the for loop it works fine by drawing two different series

```
options.series[0] = new Object();
options.series[0].name = 'Sample1';
options.series[0].data = new Array(<?php echo join(", ", $ydata[0]) ?>);

options.series[1] = new Object();
options.series[1].name = 'Sample2';
options.series[1].data = new Array(<?php echo join(", ", $ydata[1]) ?>);
```

Could somebody please help me with this problem?Is there any problem with my loop?

Comment: It draw the first serie equal to the second ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann: it draws the first series correctly but after that it draws the second series equal to the first one so i get two series overlapping each other

Comment: try to change this `<?php echo $k=0; ?>;` to `<?php $k=0; ?>;`

Comment: What shows if you log $k before `options.series[i] = new Object();` ?

Comment: It shows value of k as 0 and at the end of first iteration its value becomes 1

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON instead... use `json_encode()` to create the series... honestly it will save you a lot of hassle :)

Comment: ok..I will have to learn JSON but i want to know why is the above code not working because it is a very simple code